# Django queryset for multilevel Foreignkey reference

Tags: django, django-queryset

Following are my models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    a_name= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, unique=True)

class B(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    b_name= models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)


class C(models.Model):
    a= models.OneToOneField(
        A,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        unique=True,
    )
    b= models.OneToOneField(
        B,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        unique=True,
    )

class D(models.Model):
       c= models.OneToOneField(C,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        unique=True,
    )
    d1 = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=1)
```

I am trying to override the queryset in ListView generic class to get the list of all the objects in model 'D' where the 'owner' in model 'A' in current logged in user. I am unable to write the filter for the query.

```
D.objects.filter(self.c__a__owner==self.request.user)
```

But I am getting error as:

```
'MyListView' object has no attribute 'c__a__owner'
```

Please guide me how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: we dont use `self` just the field name

Comment: global name 'c__a__owner' is not defined is the error, now.

Comment: show the full view please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query shouldn't have `self`. Also, you use a keyword assignment instead of a comparison in the `filter` method. It should like:

```
D.objects.filter(c__a__owner=self.request.user)
```

Comment: global name 'c__a__owner' is not defined is the error, now.

Comment: Can you write full `get_queryset` method here.

Comment: Have a look at the edited answer: you should use *one* equals sign instead of two. Otherwise you try to compare `self.request.user` with the undefined variable `c__a__owner` which isn't what you want.

Comment: Yes. single equal sign worked. Can you please explain, why?

Comment: Because "==" (double equal) is a comparison operator. When you write "==", python tries to evaluate "c__a__owner==self.request.user" first, where  `c__a__owner` is undefined.

Comment: Oh. Assignment vs Comparison operators.I needed an assignment operator.  I understood now. Thanks.

Comment: @Gautam, equal in a function is not assignment operator, it is a way to pass keyword argument.

Comment: Ok. Understood.